# I have been trying to simulate this but it won't and it gives me those 2 errors

Tags: pspice

I have been trying to simulate this citcuit

[image: circuit diagram]

but it won't and it gives me those 2 errors

[image: errors]

Comment: What is "this"? Post editable code rather than a screengrab which has 80% whitespace and irrelevant buttons and frames.

Comment: Can’t find library. Fix that.

Comment: i have been trying to do that but i have installed every library in the pspice and it still gives me that error. what i am focusing on about is the other error which i really don;t understand it

Comment: http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0073380679/828076/PSpice_Instructions.pdf

Comment: try .ac dec 1k 10 10k. That will do a decade sweep of 1k points per decade from 10Hz to 10kHz. I suspect that the error you have is that 100k points per decade is too large.

Answer (score 1):

As @winny says in a comment, you need to fix the library problem **first**.

Any errors after the first one cannot be trusted to be real. I recall file locations being a bit tricky in PSPice/Orcad simulations (the simulator is very good, however).

[This](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/edit-pspice-model-error-cant-find-nomd-lib.88959/) reference suggests that you must save the library in this location: C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.2\tools\PSpice\Library. (or whatever is the equivalent in your installation).

Answer (score 0):

Why was your schematic as large as my neighborhood? Here is my copy:
[image: Mosfet]